# What is the use of this line of code with [0][1] index?

Tags: python-3.7, odoo-12

i cant find out what does name_get()[0][1]

```
display_name = product_id.name_get()[0][1]
       if product_id.description_sale:
           display_name += '\n' + product_id.description_sale
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breaking it down backwards: `[0][1]` indicates an element of a 2d array (an array that has elements which are also arrays), so therefore we can infer that the expectation is that `name_get()` returns a 2d array - we can't say anything about the type of values inside those arrays though - python is dynamically typed.

`product.name_get()` indicates that name_get() is a method/function of the product class/file.

As an example - `name_get()` might return something like

```
[ ["savings account", "current account"], ["credit card", "store card"] ]
```

so `name_get()[0][1]` would evaluate to `"current account"`